# Отправка POST без формы

Tags: php

Добрый вечер, помогите осмыслить одну вещь.. никак не получается отправить данные POSTом без формы.

Имеется картинка, при нажатии на нее хочу передать в php файл кое-какие данные (допустим ее id в базе, что хранится в $somevalue). При GET это легко, получилось бы вот так:

```
<a href="rate.php?winner=$someSalue&loser=$someValue2">
    <img src="images/someImg.jpg" />
</a>
```

Я в курсе что при poste без формы данные нужно передавать через заголовки:

```
    $data="winner=$someValue&loser=$someValue"; 
    $fp = fsockopen("site.ru", 80, $errno, $errstr, 10); 
    $out = "POST /file.php HTTP/1.1\n"; 
    $out .= "Host: site.ru\n"; 
    $out .= "Referer: site.ru/\n"; 
    $out .= "User-Agent: браузер..\n"; 
    $out .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n"; 
    $out .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\n\n"; 
    $out .= $data."\n\n"; 
    fputs($fp, $out); 
    fclose($fp);
```

Но никак не могу добиться передачи данных. Не могут понять как клика добиться. Начал раздумывать что может быть сделать через JavaScript, присвоив <img> onlick и вызвать ф-ция с php, но покопался на форумах и понял что это *авнокод получится.

В каком направлении вообще копать?

Comment: По-моему по другому никак, либо вы с помощью ajax отправляете нужные вам параметры, либо передаёте их через ссылку вида ?param=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery решение может подойдет

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $.post{"rate.php",{winner:"someValue",loser: "someValue"},function(data){
       $("#ajax_return").html(data)
    }};
    return false;
});
```

Comment: c ajax только-только начинаю ознакамливаться..   
winner:"someValue"  

моё $someValue это php переменная, ну допустим можем при выводе картинки сразу присвоить это значение, допустим в ALT  
  
как в этом отрезке спарсить ALT с img?  
  
   winner:"someValue"

Comment: `$(this).attr("alt");`

Comment: но тогда не на а нужно вешать, а на img

Comment: лучше всего использовать атрибута плана data-id и потом обращаться как к    `$("[data-id]").click(...);`

Comment: вот так?
интересует именно написание winner:"leftI" - так правильно?


    <img src="images/img.jpg" data-id='<?=$someValue?>'/>  
  

    $("[data-id]").click(function(){  
     var leftI=$(this).data('id');  
        $.post{"rate.php",{winner:"leftI",loser: "somevalue"},function(data){  
           $("#ajax_return").html(data)  
        }};  
    return false;  
    });

Comment: $.post{"rate.php",{winner:"leftI",loser: "somevalue"},function(data){
$("#ajax_return").html(data)
}};

    
"leftI" - без скобок, это же переменная

Comment: во, ништяк
спасибо огромное! :)